# How to translate breadcrumbs in Magento 2.3.2 Checkout page?

Tags: magento, translation, magento2

I've managed to translate almost everything at the moment this page [Checkout Page](https://alexanderb1.sg-host.com/checkout/cart/) has default English Breadcrumbs and Breadcrumb Title. I am not able to find how to translate it. I have my bg_BG.csv file I am updating the translations there and in most of the cases everything is working as should. Only this page stays with non translated breacrumbs. Could someone plese check it out and help me with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "/var/www/html/magento2/xx_YY.csv" -m
```

where "/var/www/html/magento2/" is path to your magento.
After that check xx_YY.csv for phrases that you are interested in and simply add you your file in case you are creating language pack, there are more details here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html